# How to confirm HTTP request including header, body and url parameter in azure mobile apps

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Hi I have a question about azure mobile apps.

Can I confirm HTTP request including header, body and url parameter in azure mobile apps when troubleshooting?
If yes, how can I confirm that?

For example, let me assume that client send a HTTP request to azure mobile apps, and a the response is bad request(status code 400). 
Then I would like to figure out the cause.

First of all I set [Diagnostics log] - [Web server logging] as Storage in portal.azure.com,and confirmed the IIS log.
But there is no header, body info in the HTTP request. 
So I did not find out the cause by that log.

Finally problem is solved by client logs by taking fiddler and cause is wrong info in body of the http request.

Above all, by taking fiddler log in client side, I was able to solve the problem but I would like to know if there is a way to confirm http request's header, body and url parameter in azure mobile apps side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log the inbound query on the client or server side, or use something like Fiddler.  For the server side, just use regular methods for Node.js or ASP.NET - nothing special is needed.  For the client side, I documented the process for [all platforms on my blog](https://shellmonger.com/2016/06/16/adjusting-the-http-request-with-azure-mobile-apps/).  Although the documentation is for adjusting the HTTP request, it's the same recipe for logging.

Comment: Here's a sample for the managed client (Windows/Xamarin): [sample LoggingHandler](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs#L63).

Comment: Thanks for giving us great info! in server side, we can get info by using methods. But I would like to know if there is default feature for taking logs of full http request including header and body. Do you know that point?

Comment: It's standard ASP.NET or Node.js/ExpressJS - so, no, there is nothing out the box - you have to do something and no standard feature logs absolutely everything.  You can easily do it yourself, however.